# Combining 2 Xarray DataArrays along 2 dimensions (in order to obtain finer grid from coarse grid)

Tags: python, geospatial, python-xarray

I have 2 DataArrays and I have to combine them, but for some reason that's not working. (the aim is to create a grid with a finer resolution (x2)).

The 1st array `da_1` contains the source data: `z` values for coordinates pairs `(x,y)`:

da_1 :

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 3, y: 2)>
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2
  * y        (y) int64 8 9
```

Then, I create a second array `da_2`: it has the same properties as `da_1`, but the grid has a finer resolution (x2), such that in `da_1` the `x` coordinates were `[0, 1, 2]` and in `da_2` that's `[0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2]`. For `y` coordinates : `[8, 9]` become `[8, 8.5, 9]`. And `z` values are all NaNs.

da_2 :

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 5, y: 3)>
array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) float64 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0
  * y        (y) float64 8.0 8.5 9.0
```

Finally, I have to replace NaNs in `da_2` that exist (have same `(x,y)` coordinates pairs) in `da_1`: `(0,8), (0,9), (1,8), (1,9), (2,8) and (2,9)`.

Expected result:

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 5, y: 3)>
array([[ 1., nan,  2.],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [ 3., nan,  4.],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [ 5., nan,  6.]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) float64 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0
  * y        (y) float64 8.0 8.5 9.0
```

To do that, I try to combine them with `xarray.combine_by_coords()` but it fails.

Calling `combine_by_coords([da_1, da_2])` returns `da_2` instead of the expected merged DataArray, and `combine_by_coords([da_2, da_1])` returns `da_1`.

I tried all joins methods with no luck.

Do you know how to get the expected result (`da_2` with the values of `da_1`)?.

**Reproducible example (See below for visual representation of these data):**

```
import xarray as xr

# Create first DataArray
da_1 = xr.DataArray([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], dims=("x", "y"), 
        coords={"x": [0,1,2], "y": [8,9]})
print(da_1)
print("*"*50)

# Create second DataArray
nan = float("NaN")
da_2_data = [[nan, nan, nan],
            [nan, nan, nan],
            [nan, nan, nan],
            [nan, nan, nan],
            [nan, nan, nan]]

da_2 = xr.DataArray(da_2_data, dims=("x", "y"), 
        coords={"x": [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2], "y": [8, 8.5, 9]})
print(da_2)
print("*"*50)

# Trying to combine
combined = xr.combine_by_coords([da_1, da_2])
print(combined)
print("*"*50)

expected_data = [[1, nan, 2],
                [nan, nan, nan],
                [3, nan, 4],
                [nan, nan, nan],
                [5, nan, 6]]

# Expected output (grid with resolution x2)
expected = xr.DataArray(expected_data, dims=("x", "y"), 
    coords={"x": [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2], "y": [8, 8.5, 9]})
print(expected)
print("*"*50)

# If all is OK, we should get the same results as in da_1 for identical coordinates
x0_y8 = expected.sel(x=0, y=8).values
x0_y9 = expected.sel(x=0, y=9).values
x1_y8 = expected.sel(x=1, y=8).values
x1_y9 = expected.sel(x=1, y=9).values
x2_y8 = expected.sel(x=2, y=8).values
x2_y9 = expected.sel(x=2, y=9).values

assert(x0_y8 == 1)
assert(x0_y9 == 2)
assert(x1_y8 == 3)
assert(x1_y9 == 4)
assert(x2_y8 == 5)
assert(x2_y9 == 6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to utilize the connection between `xarray` and `pandas`. You can check the codes below. The only concern is with the speed if your data is very big, like data frames with billions of rows in climate sciences. For other normal datasets, the below method should be fine.

```
# import packages
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# construct your sample data
da_1 = xr.DataArray([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], dims=("x", "y"), 
        coords={"x": [0,1,2], "y": [8,9]})

nan = float("NaN")
da_2_data = [[nan, nan, nan],
            [nan, nan, nan],
            [nan, nan, nan],
            [nan, nan, nan],
            [nan, nan, nan]]

da_2 = xr.DataArray(da_2_data, dims=("x", "y"), 
        coords={"x": [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2], "y": [8, 8.5, 9]})

# build a function to convert xarray to pandas dataframe
def xr_to_df(input_xr):
    df = input_xr.to_dataframe()
    df = df.reset_index(drop=False)
    return df

# assign names to variables in "da_1" and "da_2"
# so you can combine them later
da_1 = da_1.rename("da_1")
da_2 = da_2.rename("da_2")

# conver both to pandas dataframes and combine the results
da_1_df = xr_to_df(da_1)
da_2_df = xr_to_df(da_2)

# now you can see that values from "da_1" and "da_2" are already matched on coordinates
da_df_combined = pd.merge(da_1_df,da_2_df,how='right')
print(da_df_combined)

# from now, conver the above dataframe back to xarray

# first get unique X and Y
# these should be natrually sorted from min to max
x = np.unique(da_df_combined['x'])
y = np.unique(da_df_combined['y'])

print("x:",x)
print("y:",y)

# then reshape the data to match the way it is structured
da_1_reshape =da_df_combined['da_1'].values.reshape(len(x),len(y))

# generate xarray and provide a name for the variable
# since you are only interested in values from "da_1", here we do "da_1" only
da_1_xr = xr.DataArray(da_1_reshape, coords=[('x', x),('y', y)])
da_1_xr = da_1_xr.rename("da_1")

# check your results
print(da_1_xr)

# use your way to doublecheck the values
x0_y8 = da_1_xr.sel(x=0, y=8).values
x0_y9 = da_1_xr.sel(x=0, y=9).values
x1_y8 = da_1_xr.sel(x=1, y=8).values
x1_y9 = da_1_xr.sel(x=1, y=9).values
x2_y8 = da_1_xr.sel(x=2, y=8).values
x2_y9 = da_1_xr.sel(x=2, y=9).values

assert(x0_y8 == 1)
assert(x0_y9 == 2)
assert(x1_y8 == 3)
assert(x1_y9 == 4)
assert(x2_y8 == 5)
assert(x2_y9 == 6)
```

Comment: Kind of hacky (I've implemented other workarounds solutions too, that needed other libs than xarray) but it works fine, thank you! Any idea why `combine_by_coords` is not working in this example? That's surprising that if we replace y (`[8, 8.5, 9]`) with `[10, 10.5, 11]` it works...

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment on that, because I never used ````combine_by_coords```` before.

Comment: OK no problem, thanks.